# Excel delete Sheets previously created

Tags: vba, excel

I have a Macro which I have set up to go through multiple sorts and filters and at the end of each step it creates a new worksheet and pastes the filtered information.

When I want the person to be able to use the same workbook with a new set of data I want the Macro to start by deleting all of the previously created sheets.

I have tried multiple styles of code which all delete worksheets but cannot get it to delete "P High Offstd."

I have tried adjusting the orders of the delete as well as various ways to delete worksheets but it refuses to delete that worksheet.

I have even tried changing the name as it used to be called Processing High Offstd.  Any assistance would be beneficial.

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For Each Sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
If Sheet.Name = "Processing 0% Performance" Then
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Worksheets("Processing 0% Performance").Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End If
Next Sheet
For Each Sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
If Sheet.Name = "Processing 0 OnStd" Then
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Worksheets("Processing 0 OnStd").Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End If
Next Sheet
For Each Sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
If Sheet.Name = "P High OffStd" Then
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Worksheets("P High OffStd").Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End If
Next Sheet
For Each Sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
If Sheet.Name = "Processing Low Performance" Then
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Worksheets("Processing Low Performance").Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End If
Next Sheet
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Processing")
.Range("AA1:AZ" & .Range("AA1").End(xlDown).Row).ClearContents
.Range("C3:C" & .Range("C3").End(xlDown).Row).ClearContents
.Range("E3:E" & .Range("E3").End(xlDown).Row).ClearContents
End With
```

Comment: Could be that it's the last sheet in the workbook. Workbooks must have at least one sheet, so you cannot delete the last one.

Comment: Why not just delete the sheets your about to re-create from your filter with in your `For Each Loop` - no need  for all this line code-

Comment: Unfortunately it isn't the last sheet.  There is the sheet my buttons which control the MACROs exist on as well as the sheet with the source data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code can be simplified to

```
With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .DisplayAlerts = False
End With

For Each Sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If Sheet.Name = "Processing 0% Performance" Or Sheet.Name = "Processing 0 OnStd" _
    Or Sheet.Name = "P High OffStd" Or Sheet.Name = "P High OffStd" Or Sheet.Name = "Processing Low Performance" Then
        Sheet.Delete
Next Sheet

With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Processing")
    .Range("AA1:AZ" & .Range("AA1").End(xlDown).Row).ClearContents
    .Range("C3:C" & .Range("C3").End(xlDown).Row).ClearContents
    .Range("E3:E" & .Range("E3").End(xlDown).Row).ClearContents
End With
With Application
    .DisplayAlerts = True
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With
```

Comment: Tom the above code actually errors out at "Next Sheet" but I have used a similar condensed code which still failed to remove the one sheet.

Comment: How many sheets are you left with after this has run? and which sheet does it fail to remove?

Comment: 1 Sheet which is the sheet named "P High Offstd".  This sheet is the 5th sheet in the workbook.  I am aware that I could technically do a sheet count and remove sheets 3-7 but I wanted to be more accurate to avoid user error.

Comment: To avoid user error use the vba object name instead of the Sheet name. Check the sheet name that there are no additonal spaces (Including inbetween each word)

Comment: I think it was just a name issue after I removed all spaces it worked.

Comment: Glad you found it. Try to use the vba object name in future - Saves a lot of time in code and avoids a lot of errors like this

Comment: In this code the issue with using the object name is each time it creates a new sheet it adds 1 to the previous set so for instance the sheets were .sheet3-7 and then the next time it created the sheet, even though the previous sheets were deleted it named the next ones .sheet8-12.  Is there a way to avoid this when the created sheet is named?  That would solve all of my issues with using the vba object name.